# How to properly use the function ThermodynamicData?

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-cloud, chemistry

I've been trying to use the function `ThermodynamicData`, and it is going fine when I try to calculate properties such as Enthalpy or Entropy or even phase as a function of Temperature and Pressure.

Online it says i can calculate a huge number of other properties as a function of "Density", "Enthalpy", "Entropy", "InternalEnergy", "Pressure", "Quality" and "Temperature".
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThermodynamicData.html

But when I try to calculate, for example, the saturation temperature of a steam (the property "Quality" between 0 and 1):

```
ThermodynamicData["Water", "Temperature", {"Pressure" -> 
   Quantity[10000000, "Pascals"], "Quality" -> 0}]
```

it gives me the following error

```
ThermodynamicData::para: Parameter list includes parameters other than Pressure and Temperature.
```

as if it I could only calculate the properties as a function of Temperature and Pressure and nothing else.

Other inputs I tried, that had the same result were for example:

```
ThermodynamicData["Water", "Temperature", {"Pressure" -> 
   Quantity[10000000, "Pascals"], 
  "Enthalpy" -> Quantity[3.40098*10^6, ("Joules")/("Kilograms")]}]
```

Can anybody help me understand why?

Comment: Can you post the input which generated the message?

Comment: sorry. i was gonna print screen the entries, but then i forgot.
already put them

Comment: The reference you link on the web is for V12.2.  You're using V12.1. The docs for 12.1 indicate only temp and pressure may be specified.

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12/ref/ThermodynamicData.html for  the V12.0 docs online.  (V12.2 must be near its time for release. They often put a nearly-ready version up on WolframCloud ahead of time, perhaps to check for bugs. They also update the online docs before the new version is released, too.)

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are trying to use is not available in versions before V12.2.
You can try `CloudEvaluate`, but it will ding your `$CloudCreditsAvailable`:

```
CloudEvaluate[
 ThermodynamicData["Water", "Temperature",
  {"Pressure" -> Quantity[10000000, "Pascals"], "Quality" -> 0}]
 ]
```

[image]

WolframCloud is running V12.2 currently, but the rest of us have to wait until they are ready for a full release.

Answer (score 0):

ThermodynamicData["Water", "LiquidVaporPressureBoundary", {"Pressure" ->
Quantity[10000000, "Pascals"]}]

will give the temperature and

ThermodynamicData["Water", "LiquidVaporPressureBoundary", {"Temperature" ->
Quantity[373.15, "Kelvins"]}]

will give the pressure.

Comment: It doesn't evaluate on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. Could you perhaps include the output of `$Version` for your system and also the output with your answer?